# 'No specs found' showing in karma console

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am running a few tests on my angular 8 project using jasmine. In my system, it shows 46 specs passed. I pushed the code to master. However, when my colleague ran `ng test` in his system, it shows `No specs found`. But he can see that there are a lot of testcases in the `spec` files. What may be the possible reason? What should he do in his system to run the tests?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if the tsconfig.spec.json are similars and karmaTest.ts also, especially this line `const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);`